# SVN Private File

Tags: svn

I have a web-based application that I would like to open source by using a public svn host, the problem is that the project contains configuration files which I would rather keep some of the values private. What is the best way of handling this?

Ideally I would like to be able to import revisions without having to replace the file with a file stripped of private data every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maintain two configuration files:

- One named, say, `config.php`
- Another named `config.dist.php`

`config.php` is your live settings file where you store your runtime configuration with private data, paths and such.

`config.dist.php` is the same file but with default or dummy configuration settings.

Whenever your project gets a new configuration setting, you test it in your live `config.php` file and afterwards copy it into the .dist file, giving it a dummy value.

Set your version control to ignore `config.php`.

That way, you will never have private data in your repository, but somebody checking out the project has a default configuration file to start right away.

Answer (score 4):

User specific configuration files should not be part of the source of a FOSS project. If you want to version control them, keep them in a separate, private repository.

Comment: Why? You might have a file file a sample set of users with passwords or DB credentials for testing purpose.

Comment: In which case it is not user specific - I didn't say configuration files should not be part of the project.